# hudson refresh operation delete my workspace?

Tags: locking, hudson, refresh

I have two builds from the same set of source codes , if jobA starts "svn update" when jobB is "svn updating", hudson will tell me the workspace is locked and hudson refreshes the workspace , so the source codes are refreshed , hudson deletes my workspace and checks out again!

We have more than one coders that can execute build operation on hudson , so this situation has occurred multiple times , hudson can do not refresh the workspace when the workspace is locked ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but ideally it would be better to not share the same workspace for the two jobs. By default, a fresh workspace gets created per job in hudson, and once created, any new checkins are only polled and update the workspace.The workspace would be under the project folder - I am not sure how you are even sharing the spaces of the two jobs/projects. Better take a look at the project configuration details, just in case you've inherited some flawed configurations.